# write spark dataframe rows as items in dynamoDB table

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, pyspark

Is there a way to write every row of my `spark` dataframe as a new item in a `dynamoDB` table ? (in `pySpark`)

I used this code with `boto3` library, but I wonder if there's another way, avoiding the `pandas` and the `for loop` steps :

```
sparkDF_dict = sparkDF.toPandas().to_dict('records')
for item in sparkDF_dict :
    table.put_item(Item = item)
```

Comment: Has there been a resolution to this problem? So little documentation on this stuff. Seems like sending EMR output to DynamoDB should be possible.

Comment: I have the exact same requirement but need to write more than 5 million rows. Do we have a more robust and parallel solution for this?

Comment: This is the method I am following as well. However, most of the time I am receiving memory errors with millions of rows during conversion `toPandas`. I splited the DF to multiple smaller chunks, but in that case the job is taking so much time. Looking an alternative way also.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB offers a [BatchWriteItem API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html). It is [available in boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item), so you could call it after creating slices of the sparkDF_dict 25 elements long. Note, the BatchWriteItem API only supports [writing 25 items at a time](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#DDB-BatchWriteItem-request-RequestItems), and not all writes may succeed at first (as they may get throttled on the service side and come back to you in the [UnprocessedItems](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#DDB-BatchWriteItem-response-UnprocessedItems) part of the response). Your application will need to look at `UnprocessedItems` in the response and retry as needed.